# How can I change the tick marks scale in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, axes

I have a matrix A which I am plotting using imagesc(A). The matrix is a 512 X 512 matrix, but I need the axes to be labeled from 0 to 4000 instead of 0 to 512. I can't seem to find where I can change this instead of just changing from where to where the points are plotted!

Comment: I think some clarification may be needed. Are you wanting to plot the image so it spans from 0 to 4000 on each axis, or are you wanting to plot the image so it spans from 0 to 512 on each axis and then change the axis labels to make it *appear* that it's really being plotted from 0 to 4000? The first one is easy. The second one is more tricky, and I'm not sure why you would want to do it (unless you are plotting other stuff along with the image and don't feel like scaling the other points up to the range of 0 to 4000).

Comment: @Wires: If you have access to the Image Processing Toolbox, you can use IMSHOW and set the XData/YData paramters.

Answer (score 2):

Does this accomplish what you want?:

```
imagesc([0 4000],[0 4000],A);
```

Comment: It should (that was what I was typing up as well).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the XTick, YTick Property.

http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-15HXQ/index.html

Comment: I think that would be a bad idea, since setting ticks doesn't go well with zooming.